# Get ID of element that fired the Jquery function

Tags: jquery

I have a repeater, and each row will show a tool tip, each tool tip will include the row ID , this is my code :

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
        $('tr.SomeClass').qtip({
            content: {
                        text:  // here I want to get the id of the row
            },
```

Comment: could you please post some html code

Comment: `qtip()` is not part of the jQuery library, please include a link to the plugin you're using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) to loop through the elements here, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
  $('tr.SomeClass').each(function() {
    $(this).qtip({
        content: {
          text:  "My ID is: " + this.id
        }
    });
  });
});
```

With this approach, `this` refers to each `tr.SomeClass` element as you go, rather than whatever context you're in (previously `document`, since you were in a `document.ready` handler).

Comment: this worked, thank you, but I have another question : I have different Vars , and in the tool tip I want to show the correct Var (string) depending on the Row im over, so is it possible to place an if statement maybe next to the " text: " ?

Comment: @Arrabi - sure you can...what's your data source for the text depending on the row, an element in the row, a lookup object...something else?